# Good framework for logins in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks

I have a MySQL database full of members of an organization with their passwords and other accompanying data.  Is there a good PHP framework for a log-in system?  I'd like something like what they do on yahoo, where you can browse the pages without logging in but you need to log in to access certain content.

Comment: Have a look at Zend_Auth and Zend_Acl for authentication and access control. Try to get something working with these.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975260/basic-authentication-and-session-management-library-for-php

Answer (score 3):

Using a PHP framework is an excellent idea, however user authentication systems are not usually bundled with the frameworks themselves.

A PHP framework (like Symfony or CodeIgniter) can offer you some great features like: templating and layouts, automated validation, escaping of data to protect applications from attacks, cache management, smart URLs, e-mail and APIs, automated pagination, sorting, and filtering, plug-ins, ORM for databases, Internationalization etc etc.

Authentiaction is often seen as an extra and so is available as a plugin:

- [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) uses an optional system called [sfGuard](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin) and is in the form of a plugin
- [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) has several options for authentication [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-code-igniter-authentication-library-is-best). FreakAuth, Redux seem to be the market leaders here.